# nhibernate validator usage

Tags: c#, architecture, nhibernate-validator

Say I have a value object class, FullName, that is used as a property in an Employee entity class. The FullName may have a middle initial, nick name, etc; but from a domain perspective I would like to only enforce that both the FirstName and LastName properties of the FullName are valued.

I want to express this as part of an EmployeeValidator : ValidationDef{Employee} object, as opposed to an attribute.

Do I first need to make a class validator for FullName (ie, FirstAndLAstNameRequired) and then say that the FullName property in Employee is Valid (using some loquacious form of the ValidAttribute)?

As an aside, it seems that [this documentation](http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx) is still the best out there, but it does look dated at three years old. Is there anything newer that I missed?

Cheers,
Berryl

## UPDATE

I haven't figured this out yet, but I have found what is likely the best source of NHib Validator info here: http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/search/label/Validator

Here is some psuedo code to express the question better too:

```
/// <summary>A person's name.</summary>
public class FullName
{

    public virtual string FirstName { get; set; } 
    public virtual string LastName { get; set; } 
    public virtual string MiddleName { get; set; } 
    public virtual string NickName { get; set; } 
}

public class EmployeeValidator : ValidationDef<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        Define(x => x.FullName).FirstAndLastNameRequired();  // how to get here!!
    }
}
```

## UPDATE FOR DAVID

```
public class FullNameValidator : ValidationDef<FullName>
{
    public FullNameValidator() {

        Define(n => n.FirstName).NotNullable().And.NotEmpty().And.MaxLength(25);
        Define(n => n.LastName).NotNullable().And.NotEmpty().And.MaxLength(35);

        // not really necessary but cool that you can do this
        ValidateInstance
            .By(
                (name, context) => !name.FirstName.IsNullOrEmptyAfterTrim() && !name.LastName.IsNullOrEmptyAfterTrim())
            .WithMessage("Both a First and Last Name are required");
    }
}

public class EmployeeValidator : ValidationDef<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        Define(x => x.FullName).IsValid();  // *** doesn't compile !!!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the FullName validated when you validate the employee, I think you'd do something like the following:

```
public class EmployeeValidator : ValidationDef<Employee>
{
    public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        Define(x => x.FullName).IsValid();
        Define(x => x.FullName).NotNullable(); // Not sure if you need this
    }
}
```

Then the FullName Validator would just be something like:

```
public class FullNameValidator : ValidationDef<FullName>
{
    public EmployeeValidator()
    {
        Define(x => x.FirstName).NotNullable();
        Define(x => x.LastName).NotNullable();
    }
}
```

Alternatively I think you could do something like (haven't checked the syntax):

```
public class EmployeeValidator: ValidationDef<Employee>
{
public EmployeeValidator() {

    ValidateInstance.By((employee, context) => {
        bool isValid = true;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(employee.FullName.FirstName)) {
            isValid = false;
            context.AddInvalid<Employee, string>(
                "Please enter a first name.", c => c.FullName.FirstName);
        } // Similar for last name
        return isValid;
    });
}
}
```

Comment: I agree with you, basically, except that your first line doesn't compile (although it seems like just what is needed). Please see latest update on posting.

Comment: Odd.  I thought maybe I had some internal wiring that I'd forgotten about, but this method comes from the NHibernate.Validator.Cfg.Loquacious namespace.  I'm using NHibernate.Validator, Version=1.2.0.3001 - do you have the same version?

Comment: Comes from https://nhcontrib.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/nhcontrib/trunk/src/NHibernate.Validator/src/NHibernate.Validator/Cfg/Loquacious/IRelationshipConstraints.cs

Comment: @David. I am actually using v1.3.0.2001 which I built from the source last week. I just posted a question to nhusers to see why I can't use IsValid loquaciously. I wonder if I need to code up a custom Attribute class for FullName too? Will let you know.

Comment: @David. It turns out I had an implicit cast on FullName which was making NHib Val think it was in fact a string (which doesn't have an IsValid extension) as opposed to a related object (which does). Your answer was a good one the whole time. Thanks!

Comment: Great!  Glad you got it sorted.